# how to convert an object to array of objects

Tags: javascript, data-conversion

I have data in the following format

```
const data = 
{
   "sent_total":429,
   "sent_distribution":[
      {
         "date_triggered__date":"2022-12-07",
         "count":92
      },
      {
         "date_triggered__date":"2022-12-08",
         "count":337
      }
   ],
   "delivered":428,
   "delivered_distribution":[
      {
         "timestamp__date":"2022-12-07",
         "count":91
      },
      {
         "timestamp__date":"2022-12-08",
         "count":337
      }
   ],
}
```

Need help in converting this in the following format which separates the data by the key (which is sent or delivered) to an array of objects.

```
const data = [
  {
    key: sent,
    value: 429,
    distribution: [
      {
        date_triggered__date: "2022-12-07",
        count: 92,
      },
      {
        date_triggered__date: "2022-12-08",
        count: 337,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: please be more specific. "Need help" is not a real question.

Comment: You need help? Or are you expecting that someone will just do this for you? Se [Why is "Can someone help me?" Not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/14853083)

Comment: Need help, I tried but not getting the data in the desired format. If you can just point to the approach that would also be great.

Comment: The question is very clear from my point of view.

Comment: const convertedData = [
  {
    key: "sent",
    value: data.sent_total,
    distribution: data.sent_distribution
  }
]

Comment: appearently it seemed like he needed to split sent and distribution as two items of an array. But the example output is missing the distribution part and maybe was meant to be dropped and `sent` is reported as a variable instead of literal

Comment: I can't add answer here, so I've done a implementation and can be accessed by this URL: https://runkit.com/embed/nfr615wjwjla

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps:

```js
const data = 
{
   "sent_total":429,
   "sent_distribution":[
      {
         "date_triggered__date":"2022-12-07",
         "count":92
      },
      {
         "date_triggered__date":"2022-12-08",
         "count":337
      }
   ],
   "delivered":428,
   "delivered_distribution":[
      {
         "timestamp__date":"2022-12-07",
         "count":91
      },
      {
         "timestamp__date":"2022-12-08",
         "count":337
      }
   ],
}

const result = [];
Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
  const newKey = key.split("_")[0];
  let index = result.findIndex((resultItem) => resultItem.key === newKey);
  const value = key.includes("_distribution") ? null : data[key];
  const distribution = key.includes("_distribution") ? data[key] : null;
  if(index === -1) {
    result.push({
      key: newKey,
      value: value,
      distribution: distribution
    });
  } else {
    if(value)
      result[index].value = value;
    if(distribution)
      result[index].distribution = distribution;
  }
});
console.log(result);
```